# Python pandas sort groupby results

Tags: python, pandas

I'm successfully extracting and counting data from my dataframe but I'd like to sort on the resulting count values.

groupby snippet:

```
my_df.groupby('name').Id.nunique().head(5)
```

Results:

```
Name
nameA        4
nameB        1
nameC        1
nameD        6
nameE        2
```

But I'd like to order the results as follows;

```
Name
nameD        6
nameA        4
nameE        2
nameB        1
nameC        1
```

I'm assuming this should be straight forward and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Possibly just use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values)

Comment: Honestly you can just [use google](https://www.google.ca/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=Python+pandas+sort+groupby+results) and probably find your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need the groupby.  Just use value_counts().

```
>>> df.Name.value_counts()
nameD    6
nameA    4
nameE    2
nameC    1
nameB    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer if there is guaranteed to be 1 unique id per name.

Comment: That's great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
my_df.groupby('name').Id.nunique().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

@ej_f - right on.  Results for me were funny with nunique so I used count instead.

```
my_df.groupby('name').Id.count().sort_values(ascending=False)
```